# How to make a simple table with names in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I would like to have a simple table with small images and names so that when I click on a cell/item another view is displayed? how can I do that? I've got some experience with iphone development and .NET but I'm new to WP 7, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListBox` to do this as follows:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         SelectionChanged="OnListSelectionChanged">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This will display a list or table with an image and some text in a row. Your view model needs to declare some sort of collection of `Item` objects (`List<Items>` if it is static or `ObservableCollection<Items>` if things can be added / removed). Each `Item` must have at least 2 public properties, `ImageSource` (string containing path to the image) & `ItemName` (string containing description).

In the `OnListSelectionChanged` handler do this

```
var item = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Item;
// you can now access item.ItemName or item.ImageSource or other properties of Item
```

Data binding is a vast topic, and you should learn more about it before attempting to write an app. Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that deals with the basics.

Specifically for Windows Phone development, I recommend you download Charles Petzold's [free book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) and read that.